# Solve for $t$ in $0.5(11t-t^2)e^{0.1t}>20$

Tags: calculus

$0.5(11t-t^2)e^{0.1t}>20$

I did:

$$0.5(11t-t^2)e^{0.1t}>20 \\
\Leftrightarrow \frac{e^{0.1t}}{2} \cdot (11t-t^2) > 20 \\
\Leftrightarrow \frac{e^{0.1t}(11t-t^2)}{2}>20 \\
\Leftrightarrow e^{0.1t}(11t-t^2) > 10 \\
\Leftrightarrow ???$$

I want to simplify this inequation by replacing part of it with $y$, putting it in the form of $ay^2 + by +c$ and then solving the quadratic equation.

How do I do that, if possible? How do I solve this?

Comment: I don't think it can be put in that form.

Comment: @6005 Any other way then

Comment: Can we assume $t>0$?

Comment: @ErikM yes, that is correct

Answer (score 1):

**A hint (not a solution)**: Obtaining the solution to an equation of the form $xe^{x} = 1$ cannot be done using elementary operations, but it can be solved by applying the [Lambert W-function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LambertW-Function.html); the solution of $xe^x = 1$ is just $W(1)$.

Answer (score 1):

If there was no $t^2$ term, the problem could have been solved in terms of Lambert function.

This not being the case, let us consider first the function $$f(t)=\frac{1}{2}\left(11 t-t^2\right)\, e^{t/10} -20$$ and its derivative $$f'(t)=-\frac{1}{20} e^{t/10}\, (t^2+9t-110)$$ The derivative cancels when $$t^2+9t-110=0\implies t_{1,2}=-\frac{1}{2} \left(9\pm\sqrt{521}\right)$$ The second derivative test shows that $t_1$ corresponds to a minimum and $t_2$ to a maximum. Now $$f(t_2)=f(\frac{\sqrt{521}-9}{2})\approx 8.20129 >0$$ and since $f''(t_2)<0$, there are two roots to the equations (one $< t_2$ and one $>t_2$). Between the two roots, the inequality will hold.

At this point, numerical methods are required and the simplest is probably Newton method which, starting from a "reasonable" guess $t_0$ will update it according to $$t_{n+1}=t_n-\frac{f(t_n)}{f'(t_n)}$$ So, let us apply the method.

For the first root,  using $t_0=\frac{1}{4} \left(\sqrt{521}-9\right)$, the iterates will be 
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & t_n \\
 0 & 3.45636 \\
 1 & 3.79055 \\
 2 & 3.79909 \\
 3 & 3.79910  
\end{array}
\right)$$
For the second root, using $t_0=\frac{3}{4} \left(\sqrt{521}-9\right)$, the iterates will be 
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
  n & t_n \\
 0 & 10.3691 \\
 1 & 9.52804 \\
 2 & 9.31741 \\
 3 & 9.30467 \\
 4 & 9.30462 
\end{array}
\right)$$

All of the above makes that $$\frac{1}{2}\left(11 t-t^2\right)\, e^{t/10} >20$$ if $$3.79910 < t < 9.30462 $$